# Show drupal node along with comments for iphone app

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-services

I am using a REST server to pull data from a **drupal 6** site in JSON format, and then parse the JSON data inside an iphone application.

**I want to display a single, specific node, followed by all its comments. The node id will be given by the iphone application.**
I cannot do it using REST server...if I give the url as

```
<drupal site>/<REST server endpoint>/node/<node id>.json
```

then I get all relevant information about the node, except the comment.

I cannot do it using a drupal view...because I can only display one comment..not all comments. Moreover using views I have to way to specify the node id.

How to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I started working on a module for this purpose... I didn't include comments yet, but the framework might be a good place to start.

http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/nally/1365370.git/tree

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. Is there any way I can make a new **view** where it shows **all nodes followed by all comments per node**? I will later filter to my required node in the iphone app. Currently I can only show latest comment per node using views.

Comment: You could make a View of Comments, and then add a relationship to the owning View. Then set the View style to Table and then "Group By" the Owning node. You'll need to sort the comments by their post date as well.

Comment: I want to do it using views, like you said. However I have to send the node id from the iphone app so that the parent view loads only that node, and the child view shows comments. Is there a way to specify node id?

Comment: Yes, in an "argument". The nid will be in the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no straight way to get it with services module then there is a way to get the node and its comment by creating your own custom module and implementing hook_services_resources. This hook mechanism is similar to drupal menu hook.

Here's the code snippet which is written in drupal 7 but it should work in drupal 6 too.

```
Url : <drupal site>/<REST server endpoint>/my_rest_api/<node id>.json
```

Let me if it works or else i ll create the whole module in D6 and paste it here.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_services_resources().
 * my_rest_api should appear in your resource list and do enable it before using it.
 */
function YOURMODULE_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'my_rest_api' => array(
      'retrieve' => array(
        'callback' => 'getMyRestNodeWithComments',
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'nid',
            'optional' => FALSE,
            'source' => array('path' => 0),
            'type' => 'int',
          ),
        ),
        'access callback' => 'getMyRestAcces',
      ),


    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Get the node along with comment
 */
function getMyRestNodeWithComments($nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $node->comments = getMyRestCommentByNid($nid);
    return $node;

}

/**
 * Access callback.
 * TRUE for now but you change it according to your requirement
 */
function getMyRestAcces() {
  return TRUE;
}
/**
 * Get comment by nid
 */
function getMyRestCommentByNid($nid){
    //drupal 7
    $query = db_select('comment', 'c');
    $comments = $query
        ->fields('c')
        ->condition('c.nid', $nid)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
    return $comments;

    /*
    //In Drupal 6 something like this 
    $result = db_query("select * from {comment} where nid = %d",$nid);
    $records = array();
    while($row = db_fetch_array($result)){
        array_push($records, $row);
    }
    return $records; 
    */

}
```

Comment: I want to finish this project quickly and dont want to code. Anyway thanks a lot for the code!